# Deploying required bundles for Vaadin OSGI portlet to Liferay 7.3

Tags: deployment, liferay, osgi-bundle, gogo-shell, liferay-7.3

Deploying required bundles for Vaadin OSGI portlet to Liferay **7.0** with [Felix Gogo Shell](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018170271-Felix-Gogo-Shell) used to be done with the command `blade sh start`, e.g. for the bundle `vaadin-shared`:

```
blade sh start https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/8.11.3/vaadin-shared-8.11.3.jar
```

However, it doesn't work with Liferay **7.3** anymore:

```
blade sh start https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/8.11.3/vaadin-shared-8.11.3.jar
start https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/8.11.3/vaadin-shared-8.11.3.jar
gogo: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce start(Token) to any of [(Bundle[])]
```

How can I deploy the bundles to Liferay **7.3**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the Gogo shell commands `install` and `start` with Liferay **7.3**:

1. `blade sh install`

```
blade sh install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/8.11.3/vaadin-shared-8.11.3.jar
install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/8.11.3/vaadin-shared-8.11.3.jar
Bundle ID: 1210
```

2. `blade sh start`

```
blade sh start 1210
start 1210
```